# Generating unique IDs when inserting into databae

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to  insert from multiple computers in the same SQL table in PHP but it all saves in the same ID. How to make each one have a unique ID?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Do you have a primary key in your table? If you want unique ids I suggest you make the primary key `AUTO_INCREMENT`, this means it will add one to it every time you insert a new row.

Comment: i have primary key in my table... but when 2 person make insert in the same table one for example see  the id = 1 and the secand see the same on save who save first take the id = 1 and the secand take id = 2 but in my code the both take id = 1 do u understand me ?